# watchposition fires every minute on Nexus-5

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, cordova-3, nexus-5

Geo-location watch only fires every minute.  Using a Nexus-5, android 4.4.2, and cordova 3.3.1 (I've also tried 3.4.0).  It makes no difference what I define maximumAge as. The location returned is correct. In other devices I have have tested it gets fired every second. I know I can fall back on using setTimeout with getCurrentPosition, but I'd like to understand this behaviour.

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    function(){
        console.log("success");
    },
    function(){
        console.log("fail");
    },
    {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 30000
    }
);
```

Comment: Are you using the [Geolocation Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/dev/doc/index.md) or just the HTML5 Geolocation API? Because the Geolocation Plugin is not that great, and will actually be [deprecated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5977) in the next Cordova release. They suggest that you just use the HTML5 Geolocation API.

Comment: Yes the plugin was enabled, removing it fixes it.  If you put your comment as an answer I've give you a big tick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Geolocation Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/dev/doc/index.md) is not that great, and will actually be [deprecated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5977) in the next Cordova release. They suggest that you just use the [HTML5 Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation) instead, which uses the same syntax.